# Disposal of scoped objects in WebAPI 2 / MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have a temporary file object, that wraps a `File` and removes it on a call to `Dispose()`. From what I can see, when I return a response using `StreamContent`, the file stream is held open until the response has been disposed.

Unfortunately, the call to dispose the request scope, and subsequent call to `File.Delete()` is made before the consuming read from the Response pipeline has had time to close itself (despite finishing the read?).

My short term fix is to create a subtype of `StreamContent` that manually disposes of the temporary file after completion, while registering as `ExternallyOwned` in my container configuration.

I can see a few reconsiderations;

- Registering the created file, and relying on a worker to clean up afterwards (placed in Temp folder, so manual cleaning of the odd missed file is no biggie)
- Creating a custom scope that has its lifecycle outside both Request and Response.
- Current approach, of `TemporaryFileContent` handling disposal

It boils down to the disposal being called when resources have not been fully released as a part of the `Response`, and I ask this question mostly to gauge whether using `IDispose` as a temporary file cleanup mechanism with request scopes is a good idea. The files are not designed to have a lifetime outside the current request, so it seems a good fit, but I may be misusing it.